# Leaflet map GeoJSON placemarks with image slideshow

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, mapbox

I am wondering how to create leaflet map where GeoJSON placemarks provide the image slideshow as per the example below:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markers-with-image-slideshow/

I found some solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079199/webmaping-leaflet-library

But unfortunately the code isn't working properly.

Once I attach the .css style

```
.popup {
 text-align:center;
 }
  .popup .slideshow .image        { display:none; }
  .popup .slideshow .image.active { display:block; }
  .popup .slideshow img {
 width:100%;
 }
  .popup .slideshow .caption {
background:#eee;
 padding:10px;
 }
  .popup .cycle {
 padding:10px 0 20px;
 }
 .popup .cycle a.prev { float:left; }
 .popup .cycle a.next { float:right; }
```

I have got picture dissapeared. Basically the problem must lie somewhere in the code, because I cannot  move the slides next and back.

The script code looks like this:

```
 var geoJson = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
      features: [{
      type: 'Feature',
      "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-122.11587572202124, 42.937756819243909]},
      "properties": {
          'title': 'Washington, D.C.',
          'images': [
            ['https://freakplaces.com/img/Cannon_Beach17.jpg','The U.S. Capitol after the burning of Washington during the War of 1812'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/xND1MND.jpg','Ford\'s Theatre in the 19th century, site of the 1865 assassination of President Lincoln'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg','The National Cherry Blossom Festival is celebrated around the city each spring.']
          ]
      }
  }, {
      type: 'Feature',
      "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-123.97288585689788, 45.903886579968066]},
      "properties": {
          'title': 'New York City',
          'images': [
            ['https://freakplaces.com/img/Cannon_Beach17.jpg','Peter Minuit is credited with the purchase of the island of Manhattan in 1626.'],
            ['https://freakplaces.com/img/CraterLakeNP14.jpg','During the mid-19th Century, Broadway was extended the length of Manhattan.'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/Pk3DYH1.jpg','Times Square has the highest annual attendance rate of any tourist attraction in the world.']
          ]

      }
  }]};



 L.geoJson(getData(), {
onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}
  ).addTo(map);


   function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
// does this feature have a property named popupContent?
if (feature.properties && feature.properties.title) {

    var images = feature.properties.images
    var slideshowContent = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var img = images[i];

        slideshowContent += '<div class="image' + (i === 0 ? ' active' : '') + '">' +
                              '<img src="' + img[0] + '" />' +
                              '<div class="caption">' + img[1] + '</div>' +
                            '</div>';
         }

    var popupContent =  '<div id="' + feature.properties.title + '" class="popup">' +
                            '<div class="slideshow">' +
                                slideshowContent +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="cycle">' +
                                '<a href="#" class="prev">&laquo; Previous</a>' +
                                '<a href="#" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>' +
                            '</div>'
                        '</div>';

    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
}
  };



$('#map').on('click', '.popup .cycle a', function() {
    var $slideshow = $('.slideshow'),
        $newSlide;

    if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
        $newSlide = $slideshow.find('.active').prev();
        if ($newSlide.index() < 0) {
            $newSlide = $('.image').last();
        }
    } else {
        $newSlide = $slideshow.find('.active').next();
        if ($newSlide.index() < 0) {
            $newSlide = $('.image').first();
        }
    }

    $slideshow.find('.active').removeClass('active').hide();
    $newSlide.addClass('active').show();
    return false;
});





   function getData() { 
   return {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
      features: [{
      type: 'Feature',
      "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-122.11587572202124, 42.937756819243909]},
      "properties": {
          'title': 'Washington, D.C.',
          'images': [
            ['https://freakplaces.com/img/Cannon_Beach17.jpg','The U.S. Capitol after the burning of Washington during the War of 1812'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/xND1MND.jpg','Ford\'s Theatre in the 19th century, site of the 1865 assassination of President Lincoln'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg','The National Cherry Blossom Festival is celebrated around the city each spring.']
          ]
      }
  }, {
      type: 'Feature',
      "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-123.97288585689788, 45.903886579968066]},
      "properties": {
          'title': 'New York City',
          'images': [
            ['https://freakplaces.com/img/Cannon_Beach17.jpg','Peter Minuit is credited with the purchase of the island of Manhattan in 1626.'],
            ['https://freakplaces.com/img/CraterLakeNP14.jpg','During the mid-19th Century, Broadway was extended the length of Manhattan.'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/Pk3DYH1.jpg','Times Square has the highest annual attendance rate of any tourist attraction in the world.']
          ]

      }
  }]};
  }
```

I am wondering about the `getData` function. Is it really needed for this purpose at all? I don't see it in the Mapbox example.

How to make this example running?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getData() function is indeed not very usefull as it return exactly what is stored in the variable **geoJson**

But the main problem is that you are requesting the images using HTTPS from a website (http://freakplaces.com) that is not secured. Change the urls to HTTP and it will work ;)

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/fg3dorpj/

Comment: Yes, it works, although you forgot to add:

L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
 attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
 subdomains: ['a','b','c']
}).addTo( map );

to make the map tile visible.
Anyway, good help, thanks

Comment: sure, it was just an example ;)